# Rabalance in couchbase is faling with error no qurom

Tags: cluster-computing, couchbase

I am getting below error while re-balancing 6 node data cluster : 4 data 2 query\index:

```
Rebalance exited with reason [badmatch,
leader_activities_error,
default,
ns_janitor,"Bucket",apply_config,
no_quorum,
required_quorum,
all,
set,4,16,16,8,80,48,
]
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.